# Text box validation using regular expression

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox and have to use the regular expressions in asp.net

My text should not allow the spaces in first and last place. In between words it can allow.
that means: it should allow alphabets, numbers and all special characters.

### Output should be:

India Bangalore -valid
India Bangalore - not valid
!India bangalore - valid
India bangalore!@#$%- valid
IndiaBangalore - valid

i.e : use can enter the spaces in between the words but not in first position and last position.

Java script  also fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example

```
// Input string
```

string st = "  This is an example string. ";

// Call Trim instance method.
// This returns a new string copy.

st = st.Trim();

Answer (score 0):

U can get the index, i mean index(0) is the first position of textbox and calculate the length of ur input +1 = last index of ur input validate white space validation now. damn sure it will work